# What's a simple key-value storage system that's cheaper than Redis?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, nosql, storage, serverless

I am writing a simple app, split in front end / back end, the latter being in node.js

I do need to save some data (basically caching). The idea is to have a process running every day or so that will aggregate some data and save it somewhere as JSON ready to be used by the front end. Front end will ask for the data of a given key and get the corresponding JSON.

I used redis and it works perfectly, but now that I am looking into hosting, I'm realizing that it gets pretty expensive (cheapest Redis instance on GCP is about 35usd a month). This is an app that will see very little use, it's mostly a personal project and it doesn't matter if it's a bit slow, I just want to keep the costs as low as possible.

I was thinking of having the front end hosted on gitlab pages (free), back end being 2 GCP functions (1 to prepare the data, 1 as web server)(pay per second used, which will be so little it'll be virtually free), so it's really just the data storage that is blocking me right now.

There is quite a bit of data (around 100-200k keys, total about 200-500Mo before looking into compression), which means even setting up a redis on a VPS doesn't seem like the best option and if I did take a VPS (which I would prefer to avoid if possible) - cheap VPSs have usually little RAM, so I should still find a system that saves on drive instead of in-memory.

Hosting could be wherever, so far I've looked mostly into AWS, GCP and Heroku. I've found that Firebase (GCP) or DynamoDB (AWS) seem like they could work and still be cheap (i'd be barely above the free threshold on GCP), but I don't know much about those. I've also read about things like LMDB or SSDB but it seems like I would need to get a VPS and fiddle to get them to work with node. Finally I could also store that in a SQL database, or even in plain files but that just seems too dirty.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Did you check RedisLabs pricing https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/pricing/? You can get 250MB in $12/m

Comment: That seems to be similar prices compared to AWS (micro tier is about 12 per month for 500mb). I just think there's a way to do much cheaper (free or close) by moving away from redis, given I don't need the performance

Comment: How many read/write do you perform per day?

Comment: Write about 130k daily. Read extremely few

Comment: Sound that Firebase [Blaze Plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-calculator) $0.18/GiB is the cheapest option, Firebase offers [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) that it is a key value database for $0.18/GiB and you can use [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql) in the same firebase project

Comment: The cost from Firebase would mostly be the writes - around 3M a month would be around $5/m. Def competitive, but I've looked into it a bit more today and found a few options around that price mark. I think I'm gonna try to run my own redis server on GCP's free tier VPS and see if it's good enough, otherwise main options are sql instead of redis on that free VPS, better VPS (around $5/m), DynamoDB or Firebase ($5/m too but need to edit my code), or worst case scenario AWS's 500mb redis is first year free then $12/m

Comment: Datastore is another option: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/

Comment: @BPruvost What did you choose finally?

Comment: @Ayyappa I did it by running my own redis server on a VPS in GCP free tier. Worked fine, but it did eventually lead to some obscure and relatively high fees (20ish $/m) that GCP "entry" support was unable to explain without consulting tech support, which I wasn't eligible too. This coincided with a big change in an API I was using, and those 2 together kinda killed my motivation to keep this project online, so I'm only using this locally as a personal tool now.
Self hosted redis would be the direction I'd look into if I were you though ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Even I tried earlier self hosting on gcp but unfortunately, the free vm's are burstable (so they scale up to 1vCPU leading to costs). If your volume is low, give a try with upstash which i see good for lower volumes. Later for higher volumes you can go for GCP's redis memory store.